# Centering menu bar with CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, center

I have two problems with my menu bar. What I want to achieve is to center the links on the header (including the logo picture) and have exactly the same height for the header as the menu. When I add the links it creates a margin on top and on bottom (so the header will extend) and I have no idea why. The margin size depends on the font size and if I want to remove it I have to add a -something px margin and have to try pixel by pixel what the number should be. I'm pretty sure there's an easier solution to that... My other problem is that I can't center the whole menu bar within the header unless I specify a specific width. Obviously I don't know how wide my menu bar will be (and even if I measure it somehow, what if I change the links later?) I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS so I've probably made a bunch of mistakes, I just keep changing the codes until I get what I want but since I'm trying to learn it better I'm aiming for more understanding than random coding so feel free to correct anything. Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="images/style.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Belleza' rel='stylesheet'   type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><img src="images/ncs.png" /></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
<li id="right"><a href="#">English</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
background-color: #efe8df;
}

#header {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: #afafaf;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
}

#menu {
margin: auto;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
font-family:'Belleza', sans-serif;
color: white;
font-size: 22px;
/*width: 1000px;*/
height: auto;
position: relative;
}

#menu li {
list-style: none;
width: auto;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
border-right: 1px solid #ebeaea;
}

#menu li a {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 30px;
border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

#menu li a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 30px;
border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

#menu li a:hover {
color: #46b5c2;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #ebeaea;
display: block;
padding: 30px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #46b5c2;
}

#menu li a:active {
color: #46b5c2;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #ebeaea;
display: block;
padding: 30px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #46b5c2;
}

#menu #right {
border-right: 0px;
font-family: Georgia;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header is extending because for ul and li  all browser have there margin and padding standards.
You should use reset.css and normalize.css to remove default css property of some common elements.

so if you want just for list use

`ul,li{margin:0; padding:0}` or how much you want.

To center align you can give following css properties

**to header**

```
display: table
```

**to menu**

```
display : table-cell;
text-align:center
```

**to ul**

```
display:inline-block
```

**to li**

```
 float:left
```

Check fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gJFy8/1/

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! Now I can center the menu bar without knowing the exact width of the menu :) Also I never heard about reset and normalize.css before but I'm definitely gonna use it from now on! Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in your css, change the width to whatever you want according to your need

```
#menu {

width: 900px;
```

Answer (score 0):

add width to the #menu div

```
menu {
margin: auto;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
font-family: 'Belleza', sans-serif;
color: white;
font-size: 22px;
width: 1000px;
height: auto;
position: relative;
width: 960px; //or whatever
}
```